# TS Typings for Docker variable ENV error when using SSR

Tags: angular, docker, environment-variables, typescript-typings

I followed this [tutorial](https://codinglatte.com/posts/angular/using-os-environment-variables-in-angular-with-docker/) to use env variable in Angular with docker

Everything seems quite easy to configure, however when I build my project, there is error

```
...\server\main.js:12952
apiUrl: $ENV.API_URL || "http://localhost:3000",
        ^
ReferenceError: $ENV is not defined
```

I suspect the **src/typings.d.ts** to be forgotten

src/typings.d.ts

```
declare var $ENV: Env;

interface Env {
  API_URL: string,
}
```

Should I modify the tsconfig files ? there is no clear documentation about it.

- tsconfig.json

  ```
  {
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
   }
  }
  ```
- tsconfig.app.json

  ```
  {
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
  }
  ```
- tsconfig.server.json

  ```
  {
  "extends": "./tsconfig.app.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/server",
    "target": "es2016",
    "types": [
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.server.ts",
    "server.ts"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "entryModule": "./src/app/app.server.module#AppServerModule"
  }
  }
  ```
- tsconfig.spec.json

  ```
  {
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/spec",
    "types": [
      "jasmine"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.spec.ts",
  ]
  }
  ```

**Update**

The custom webpack code

```
"projects": {
    "name-of-the-project": {
      //...
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder":"@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser"_,
          "options": {
            "customWebpackConfig": {
                "path":"custom-webpack.config.js"
            },
            //...
        //...
    }
```

custom-webpack.config.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      $ENV: {
        API_URL: JSON.stringify(process.env.API_URL)
      }
    })
  ]
};
```

**UPDATE**

I did all from scratch and the tutorial is working only without SSR (ng add @nguniversal/express-engine). After installing SSR the typings.d.ts is not taken into account anymore  :(

**Step to reproduce the issue:**

```
ng new app
```

follow tutorial listed in the first line of this post

create dockerfile

```
#stage 1
FROM node:latest as node
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
# SET ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES
ENV ENVIRONMENT=production1
ENV SomeAPIKey="This is not an API Key"
ENV SomeOtherAPIKey="This is not another API Key"
COPY . .
RUN npm run build --prod

#stage 2
FROM nginx:alpine

COPY --from=node /app/dist/app /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 80
```

Build docker :

```
docker build . test
```

Run docker :

```
docker run test
```

It works !!!

If now I add ng add @nguniversal/express-engine

I have to replace my dockerfile to take into account SSR but then I have this error :(

```
Compiled successfully.
/Users/xxx/Dev/app/dist/app/server/main.js:116
    environment: $ENV.ENVIRONMENT,
                 ^

ReferenceError: $ENV is not defined
```

Comment: Why you wanna expose the env variables in the UI in the first place :/

Comment: UI is connected to external API, I prefer to provide the API URL via docker-compose environment variable rather than in the environment.prod.ts / environment.ts. For me it is easier to maintain. The issue seems quite easy to solve but I'm struggling with TypeScript custom typings.

Comment: I can't seem to find the `custom-webpack.config.js` from the tutorial, which looks pretty much essential to what you're trying to do in what you showed us

Comment: yes it is well explained, but my main issue is the typings.d.ts not recognized. I have updated my question with more details

Comment: Yes, but did you import the `module` as described in step 3 [here](https://angular.io/guide/using-libraries#library-typings)?

Comment: The issue is somewhere else. I recreated from scratch a new angular app and followed the tutorial and it works. It might be conflicting  with some config or SSR

Comment: If you do not find a way: Maybe [this](https://calzone.proofofpizza.com/tech/tutorial/Angular-environment-variables-at-runtime/) might work. Disclaimer: I wrote that. You could change the last part and have the bash script overwrite your config with sed, if you'd prefer of course. But that should work. With minimal complexity, so magical angular stuff like installing SSR or upgrading versions should not cause problems.

Comment: Thanks Chai for the sharing, however I would like to find a way to make my custom TS type working with SSR and like that I would be able to use ENV as it is supposed without too much manipulating of the code e.g sed or script in the head of HTML.